# Get Data From PHP Object (Facebook SDK)

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I have some PHP code that **returns an object.** This is from the Facebook PHP Business SDK.

I then run a function to **beautify the output of `print_r`** so we can read it properly.

```
$account = new AdAccount('act_307978786963089');

$params = array(
  'date_preset' => "this_month",
);
$insights = $account->getInsights(array("account_name"), $params);

function my_print_r($thing,$description=false){
    echo '<pre style="background:#fff; padding:10px; color:#111; font-family:monospace; font-size:12px; border:1px solid #555">';
    if($description) echo '<strong>'.$description.'</strong><br><br>';
    print_r($thing);
    echo '</pre>';
}

my_print_r($insights);
```

It returns this:

```
    FacebookAds\Cursor Object
(
    [response:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Response Object
        (
            [request:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Request Object
                (
                    [client:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Client Object
                        (
                            [requestPrototype:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Request Object
                                (
                                    [client:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Client Object
 *RECURSION*
                                    [headers:protected] => 
                                    [method:protected] => GET
                                    [protocol:protected] => https://
                                    [domain:protected] => 
                                    [path:protected] => 
                                    [graphVersion:protected] => 
                                    [queryParams:protected] => 
                                    [bodyParams:protected] => 
                                    [fileParams:protected] => 
                                )

                            [responsePrototype:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Response Object
                                (
                                    [request:protected] => 
                                    [statusCode:protected] => 
                                    [headers:protected] => 
                                    [body:protected] => 
                                    [content:protected] => 
                                )

                            [defaultRequestHeaders:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Headers Object
                                (
                                    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [User-Agent] => fbbizsdk-php-v8.0
                                            [Accept-Encoding] => *
                                        )

                                )

                            [adapter:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Adapter\CurlAdapter Object
                                (
                                    [curl:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Adapter\Curl\Curl55 Object
                                        (
                                            [handle:protected] => Resource id #58
                                        )

                                    [opts:protected] => ArrayObject Object
                                        (
                                            [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [78] => 10
                                                    [13] => 60
                                                    [19913] => 1
                                                    [42] => 1
                                                    [10065] => /home/jack/public_html/FBTests/_/composerNew/vendor/facebook/php-business-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/../../../fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [client:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Client Object
 *RECURSION*
                                )

                            [caBundlePath:protected] => /home/jack/public_html/FBTests/_/composerNew/vendor/facebook/php-business-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/../../../fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt
                            [defaultGraphBaseDomain:protected] => facebook.com
                        )

                    [headers:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Headers Object
                        (
                            [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [User-Agent] => fbbizsdk-php-v8.0
                                    [Accept-Encoding] => *
                                )

                        )

                    [method:protected] => GET
                    [protocol:protected] => https://
                    [domain:protected] => graph.facebook.com
                    [path:protected] => /act_307978786963089/insights
                    [graphVersion:protected] => 8.0
                    [queryParams:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Parameters Object
                        (
                            [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [date_preset] => this_month
                                    [fields] => account_name
                                    [access_token] => EAAKMdiRxiAYBAFgMI98KJpipHpoEd7ZBCXNPCd0ZCiOXf5ckFzawGpvnVfa6Ohnh10y1Hm2ZBoJIlH6w6CJF8knAtqz2OnOMZCmv7RA5W8zNKx6ZCZBJSRZCZANnVNi2nfYCfnIyZAfTkiRyxNjuZBwd8qzi6gZBBtQFcwAlYVR3CoTqqvrxzAYgiZCn
                                    [appsecret_proof] => a13c6f9132c2179e5edae14d3d5dda81d98b8a4ae1f43635ffab1ae311f403a7
                                )

                        )

                    [bodyParams:protected] => 
                    [fileParams:protected] => 
                )

            [statusCode:protected] => 200
            [headers:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Headers Object
                (
                    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                        (
                            [http_code] => HTTP/2 200 
                            [etag] => "cc70d7a64f1f2d8f3aed3c50a00b79776a7064ff"
                            [x-fb-insights-stability-throttle] => {"throttled":false,"backend_qps":{"actual_score":0,"limit":300000},"complexity_score":{"actual_score":0,"limit":16000}}
                            [expires] => Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
                            [content-type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
                            [facebook-api-version] => v8.0
                            [x-fb-request-id] => AP6FXiyYQutj6UcUxnlXX_B
                            [strict-transport-security] => max-age=15552000; preload
                            [x-fb-trace-id] => H0H221WEtTK
                            [x-fb-rev] => 1002954105
                            [cache-control] => private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
                            [vary] => Accept-Encoding
                            [pragma] => no-cache
                            [x-fb-ads-insights-throttle] => {"app_id_util_pct": 0.01,"acc_id_util_pct": 0.67}
                            [x-business-use-case-usage] => {"307978786963089":[{"type":"ads_insights","call_count":1,"total_cputime":2,"total_time":2,"estimated_time_to_regain_access":0}]}
                            [access-control-allow-origin] => *
                            [x-fb-debug] => UHmcev1Xu9DiiAjBAf0De1mafdI7NvWGL0/oEF+TyMI9bZCiZCvUk8mvsWislgWQ2DJTMcpynO548nA7264s8A==
                            [content-length] => 166
                            [date] => Wed, 11 Nov 2020 04:42:40 GMT
                            [alt-svc] => h3-29=":443"; ma=3600,h3-27=":443"; ma=3600
                        )

                )

            [body:protected] => {"data":[{"account_name":"B1 - A3 - Butt Seat Cushion","date_start":"2020-11-01","date_stop":"2020-11-11"}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"MAZDZD","after":"MAZDZD"}}}
            [content:protected] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [account_name] => B1 - A3 - Butt Seat Cushion
                                    [date_start] => 2020-11-01
                                    [date_stop] => 2020-11-11
                                )

                        )

                    [paging] => Array
                        (
                            [cursors] => Array
                                (
                                    [before] => MAZDZD
                                    [after] => MAZDZD
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [api:protected] => FacebookAds\Api Object
        (
            [session:FacebookAds\Api:private] => FacebookAds\Session Object
                (
                    [appId:protected] => 717388998871046
                    [appSecret:protected] => 0d3c4be5aebb5861f3a10d6c12b4f487
                    [accessToken:protected] => EAAKMdiRxiAYBAFgMI98KJpipHpoEd7ZBCXNPCd0ZCiOXf5ckFzawGpvnVfa6Ohnh10y1Hm2ZBoJIlH6w6CJF8knAtqz2OnOMZCmv7RA5W8zNKx6ZCZBJSRZCZANnVNi2nfYCfnIyZAfTkiRyxNjuZBwd8qzi6gZBBtQFcwAlYVR3CoTqqvrxzAYgiZCn
                    [appSecretProof:protected] => a13c6f9132c2179e5edae14d3d5dda81d98b8a4ae1f43635ffab1ae311f403a7
                )

            [logger:protected] => FacebookAds\Logger\NullLogger Object
                (
                )

            [httpClient:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Client Object
                (
                    [requestPrototype:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Request Object
                        (
                            [client:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Client Object
 *RECURSION*
                            [headers:protected] => 
                            [method:protected] => GET
                            [protocol:protected] => https://
                            [domain:protected] => 
                            [path:protected] => 
                            [graphVersion:protected] => 
                            [queryParams:protected] => 
                            [bodyParams:protected] => 
                            [fileParams:protected] => 
                        )

                    [responsePrototype:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Response Object
                        (
                            [request:protected] => 
                            [statusCode:protected] => 
                            [headers:protected] => 
                            [body:protected] => 
                            [content:protected] => 
                        )

                    [defaultRequestHeaders:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Headers Object
                        (
                            [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [User-Agent] => fbbizsdk-php-v8.0
                                    [Accept-Encoding] => *
                                )

                        )

                    [adapter:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Adapter\CurlAdapter Object
                        (
                            [curl:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Adapter\Curl\Curl55 Object
                                (
                                    [handle:protected] => Resource id #58
                                )

                            [opts:protected] => ArrayObject Object
                                (
                                    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [78] => 10
                                            [13] => 60
                                            [19913] => 1
                                            [42] => 1
                                            [10065] => /home/jack/public_html/FBTests/_/composerNew/vendor/facebook/php-business-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/../../../fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt
                                        )

                                )

                            [client:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Client Object
 *RECURSION*
                        )

                    [caBundlePath:protected] => /home/jack/public_html/FBTests/_/composerNew/vendor/facebook/php-business-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/../../../fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt
                    [defaultGraphBaseDomain:protected] => facebook.com
                )

            [defaultGraphVersion:protected] => 8.0
        )

    [objects:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => FacebookAds\Object\AdsInsights Object
                (
                    [data:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [account_currency] => 
                            [account_id] => 
                            [account_name] => B1 - A3 - Butt Seat Cushion
                            [action_values] => 
                            [actions] => 
                            [ad_bid_type] => 
                            [ad_bid_value] => 
                            [ad_click_actions] => 
                            [ad_delivery] => 
                            [ad_id] => 
                            [ad_impression_actions] => 
                            [ad_name] => 
                            [adset_bid_type] => 
                            [adset_bid_value] => 
                            [adset_budget_type] => 
                            [adset_budget_value] => 
                            [adset_delivery] => 
                            [adset_end] => 
                            [adset_id] => 
                            [adset_name] => 
                            [adset_start] => 
                            [age_targeting] => 
                            [auction_bid] => 
                            [auction_competitiveness] => 
                            [auction_max_competitor_bid] => 
                            [buying_type] => 
                            [campaign_id] => 
                            [campaign_name] => 
                            [canvas_avg_view_percent] => 
                            [canvas_avg_view_time] => 
                            [catalog_segment_actions] => 
                            [catalog_segment_value] => 
                            [catalog_segment_value_mobile_purchase_roas] => 
                            [catalog_segment_value_omni_purchase_roas] => 
                            [catalog_segment_value_website_purchase_roas] => 
                            [clicks] => 
                            [conversion_rate_ranking] => 
                            [conversion_values] => 
                            [conversions] => 
                            [converted_product_quantity] => 
                            [converted_product_value] => 
                            [cost_per_15_sec_video_view] => 
                            [cost_per_2_sec_continuous_video_view] => 
                            [cost_per_action_type] => 
                            [cost_per_ad_click] => 
                            [cost_per_conversion] => 
                            [cost_per_dda_countby_convs] => 
                            [cost_per_estimated_ad_recallers] => 
                            [cost_per_inline_link_click] => 
                            [cost_per_inline_post_engagement] => 
                            [cost_per_one_thousand_ad_impression] => 
                            [cost_per_outbound_click] => 
                            [cost_per_store_visit_action] => 
                            [cost_per_thruplay] => 
                            [cost_per_unique_action_type] => 
                            [cost_per_unique_click] => 
                            [cost_per_unique_conversion] => 
                            [cost_per_unique_inline_link_click] => 
                            [cost_per_unique_outbound_click] => 
                            [cpc] => 
                            [cpm] => 
                            [cpp] => 
                            [created_time] => 
                            [ctr] => 
                            [date_start] => 2020-11-01
                            [date_stop] => 2020-11-11
                            [dda_countby_convs] => 
                            [engagement_rate_ranking] => 
                            [estimated_ad_recall_rate] => 
                            [estimated_ad_recall_rate_lower_bound] => 
                            [estimated_ad_recall_rate_upper_bound] => 
                            [estimated_ad_recallers] => 
                            [estimated_ad_recallers_lower_bound] => 
                            [estimated_ad_recallers_upper_bound] => 
                            [frequency] => 
                            [full_view_impressions] => 
                            [full_view_reach] => 
                            [gender_targeting] => 
                            [impressions] => 
                            [inline_link_click_ctr] => 
                            [inline_link_clicks] => 
                            [inline_post_engagement] => 
                            [instant_experience_clicks_to_open] => 
                            [instant_experience_clicks_to_start] => 
                            [instant_experience_outbound_clicks] => 
                            [interactive_component_tap] => 
                            [labels] => 
                            [location] => 
                            [mobile_app_purchase_roas] => 
                            [objective] => 
                            [outbound_clicks] => 
                            [outbound_clicks_ctr] => 
                            [place_page_name] => 
                            [purchase_roas] => 
                            [qualifying_question_qualify_answer_rate] => 
                            [quality_ranking] => 
                            [quality_score_ectr] => 
                            [quality_score_ecvr] => 
                            [quality_score_organic] => 
                            [reach] => 
                            [social_spend] => 
                            [spend] => 
                            [store_visit_actions] => 
                            [unique_actions] => 
                            [unique_clicks] => 
                            [unique_conversions] => 
                            [unique_ctr] => 
                            [unique_inline_link_click_ctr] => 
                            [unique_inline_link_clicks] => 
                            [unique_link_clicks_ctr] => 
                            [unique_outbound_clicks] => 
                            [unique_outbound_clicks_ctr] => 
                            [unique_video_continuous_2_sec_watched_actions] => 
                            [unique_video_view_15_sec] => 
                            [updated_time] => 
                            [video_15_sec_watched_actions] => 
                            [video_30_sec_watched_actions] => 
                            [video_avg_time_watched_actions] => 
                            [video_continuous_2_sec_watched_actions] => 
                            [video_p100_watched_actions] => 
                            [video_p25_watched_actions] => 
                            [video_p50_watched_actions] => 
                            [video_p75_watched_actions] => 
                            [video_p95_watched_actions] => 
                            [video_play_actions] => 
                            [video_play_curve_actions] => 
                            [video_play_retention_0_to_15s_actions] => 
                            [video_play_retention_20_to_60s_actions] => 
                            [video_play_retention_graph_actions] => 
                            [video_thruplay_watched_actions] => 
                            [video_time_watched_actions] => 
                            [website_ctr] => 
                            [website_purchase_roas] => 
                            [wish_bid] => 
                        )
```

I'm fairly decent at PHP, however, I can't figure out how to get data out of this object.

Such as the "account_name", which I can see in this part:

```
 [body:protected] => {"data":[{"account_name":"B1 - A3 - Butt Seat Cushion","date_start":"2020-11-01","date_stop":"2020-11-11"}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"MAZDZD","after":"MAZDZD"}}}
```

Could someone show me all the different ways I can extract data from this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look at the source code [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk/blob/master/src/FacebookAds/Cursor.php) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk/blob/master/src/FacebookAds/Http/Response.php), `$insights` is the instance of FacebookAds\Cursor class, so you can use:

```
$insights->getResponse()->getContent()
```

to get the content of the response in the form of an arrray